# extract each child node to create XML with parent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

I have an input XML like follwing. I need to extract each child `<DETS>` and create a new XML by merging it with its common parent nodes.

Input:

```
<STDS>
    <DEPT>ABC</DEPT>
    <COD>123</COD>
    <PIN>456</PIN>
    <DETS>
        <NAM>XYZ</NAM>
        <AGE>21</AGE>
    </DETS>
    <DETS>
        <NAM>KLM</NAM>
        <AGE>22</AGE>
    </DETS>
</STDS>

I need the output like following.
```

Output:

```
<Students>
    <Department>ABC</Department>
    <Code>123</Code>
    <Pin>456</Pin>
    <Details>
        <Name>XYZ</Name>
        <Age>21</Age>
    </Details>
</Students>
<Students>
    <Department>ABC</Department>
    <Code>123</Code>
    <Pin>456</Pin>
    <Details>
        <Name>KLM</Name>
        <Age>22</Age>
    </Details>
</Students>
```

I have tried it using the for-each but I'm unable to.

here is the code which I'm trying. If I keep the for-each inside the `<students>` it'll create new XML for each child inside `<students>`. if I use the for-each XML outside, how can access elements of `<Students>` out of the scope.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 userCSharp" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="Students" xmlns:s0="STDS" xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:STDS" />
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/s0:STDS">
    <ns0:Students>
        <xsl:for-each select="s0:STDS">
            <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="s0:DEPT" />
            <Department>
            <xsl:value-of select="$var:v1" />
            </Department>
            <xsl:variable name="var:v2" select="s0:COD" />
            <Code>
            <xsl:value-of select="$var:v2" />
            </Code>
            <xsl:variable name="var:v3" select="s0:PIN)" />
            <Pin>
            <xsl:value-of select="$var:v3" />
            </Pin>

            <xsl:for-each select="s0:STDS/s0:DETS">
                <ns0:Details>
                <xsl:variable name="var:v4" select="s0:DETS/s0:NAM" />
                <Name>
                <xsl:value-of select="$var:v4" />
                </Name>
                <xsl:variable name="var:v5" select="s0:DETS/s0:AGE" />
                <Age>
                <xsl:value-of select="$var:v5" />
                </Age>
                <ns0:Details>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    <ns0:Students>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please edit the question and share the tried XSL so that it can be modified. The output XML shows that you are also renaming all the nodes to new names from the input XML.

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: Why do you want to use Xsl?  This can be done with just one Functoid in the Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `../` feature can be used to traverse through the XML levels from child context to parent context.

Following is the XSL template that you can use. Please note that the input XML shared does not have any namespaces declared hence there is no reference of namespaces in the below solution. This should give you the desired output.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="STDS/DETS">
        <Students>
            <Department><xsl:value-of select="../DEPT" /></Department>
            <Code><xsl:value-of select="../COD" /></Code>
            <Pin><xsl:value-of select="../PIN" /></Pin>
            <Details>
                <Name><xsl:value-of select="NAM" /></Name>
                <Age><xsl:value-of select="AGE" /></Age>
            </Details>
        </Students>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, **you do not need custom Xslt to do this in BizTalk**.  It just adds unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 0):

The Question is tagged **BizTalk**.  This is the proper **BizTalk** Asnwer.

In the Mapper all you need to do is **connect `<DETS>` to `<Students>` through a Looping Functoid**.

That's all, *no custom xslt required*.  Yes, it's that simple.

__

There is no way to edit the Answer since *it's the same Answer* for two different questions.  This is a **BizTalk specific** situation.  The question is tagged **BizTalk**.  While they maybe technically correct, the Xsl Answers are not the proper way to do this in **BizTalk**.

Deleting this Answer just removes the proper **BizTalk domain specific** Answer.  If this Answer is deleted again, fine, I'll just give up and OP can struggle with an **unnecessarily complicated and wrong** (for BizTalk) solution.